# ¿Cómo deshabilitar el botón cuando edittext está vacío en la vista de lista en un fragmento?

Tags: botón, listview, fragment, edittext

Necesito que el botón se desactive y se active cuando se escribe en el texto de edición, aparte cuando hago clic en el botón, me envía un mensaje y se borra lo que se ingresó en el texto de edición, esto debe ejecutarse en cada elemento de la lista, lo he intentado, la aplicación se ejecuta pero no hace nada de lo que quiero, hice esto en un fragmento, por favor ayúdenme.

HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button ingresar;
    EditText rspuesta;

    int[] imagen = new int[]{
            R.drawable.gotas,R.drawable.hojas,R.drawable.leon
    };

    String[] nombreimagen = new String[]{
            "gota","hojas","animal"
    };

    String[] pregunta = new String[] {
            "¿cuantas gotas han caido?","¿cuantas hojas hay?","¿que animal es?"
    };
    String[] numreto = new String[]{
            "reto 1","reto 2","reto 3"

    };
    String[] descripcion = new String[]{
            "escribe un numero","escribe un numero","escribe un numero"
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i<3 ; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String > hm = new HashMap<>();
            hm.put("ima", Integer.toString(imagen[i]));
            hm.put("nombreima", nombreimagen[i]);
            hm.put("pregunta", pregunta[i]);
            hm.put("numreto", numreto[i]);
            hm.put("descri", descripcion[i]);
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        String[] from = {"ima", "nombreima", "pregunta", "numreto", "descri"};

        int[] to = {R.id.imagret, R.id.nombreima, R.id.pregun, R.id.numreto, R.id.descrp};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(view.getContext(), aList, R.layout.item2, from, to);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                int viewId = view.getId();
                switch (viewId){
                    case R.id.ingre:
                        //Boton Detalles

                        ((ListView) container).performItemClick(view,i,0);
                        ingresar.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) rspuesta);
                        ingresar.setEnabled(false);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"su respuesta" + rspuesta + "se ingreso",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    case R.id.respuesta:

                        rspuesta.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                                if(charSequence.toString().equals("")){
                                    ingresar.setEnabled(false);
                                }
                                else{
                                    ingresar.setEnabled(true);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                                if (editable.toString().equals("")){
                                    ingresar.setEnabled(false);
                                }
                                else {
                                    ingresar.setEnabled(true);
                                }

                            }
                        });


                        break;
            }
        }
        });
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.ingre:{
                rspuesta.setText("");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item2

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="293dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagret"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="219dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nombreima"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="293dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pregun"
            android:layout_width="215dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#0091EA"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="293dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numreto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="38sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descrp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/respuesta"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Cantidad"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorLink="#0037CE"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ingre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:text="ingresar"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

esta es mi aplicación, el botón debe comenzar (deshabilitado) y al escribir el texto de edición debe (estar habilitado), después de hacer clic en el botón debe eliminar lo que tiene en el texto de edición, esto debe ejecutarse en cada elemento, después de esto guardará las respuestas en una base de datos para comparar y el resultado final (pero esto es más tarde, solo si me pueden ayudar con esto también, lo agradecería) por el momento solo necesito los botones y el texto de edición por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: only the id are in spanish the layout shows who belongs, I already edited it

Comment: quieres que lo traduzca a español

Comment: no puedo escribir  en ingles y despues en español

Comment: ok esque la ultima pregunta que hice la puse en español y se borro la pregunta así que la traduje a ingles y entonces me la aceptaron

Comment: ahí esta bien ya lo traduje